# Android: Intent not fetching data to the mainactivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have 2 Activities, from the second `Activity`'s `OnCreate` I am doing this:

```
setPassButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
            if(getPass1 == getPass2) {
                Intent gotoMain = new Intent(FirstRun.this, MainActivity.class);
                gotoMain.putExtra("getPass1", getPass1);
                startActivity(gotoMain);
```

In the first `Activity`, I am trying to fetch this `getPass1`, but it always gives me `-1`. What am I missing here? 
This is also in `OnCreate` of the `MainActivity`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
iSelectedItem = intent.getIntExtra("getPass1", -1);
System.out.println("Password is " + iSelectedItem);
```

Comment: is it possible that getPass1 == getPass2 == -1 ?

Comment: debug this and figure out the values of getPass1 and getPass2 via Log.d("DEBUG", "getPass1: " + getPass1 + " and getPass2: " + getPass2);

Comment: are you sure getpass1 is integer??

Comment: getPass1 is a 4 digit number that the user enters.. It's not -1.
I am printing it before Onclicklistener to confirm.

Comment: Can you post your whole activity code? @RohitG

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
iSelectedItem = intent.getExtras().getInt("getPass1", -1);
System.out.println("Password is " + iSelectedItem);
```

Comment: I tried your approach, it doesn't event print the System.out.println("Password is" ... )

Comment: Post your complete activity class code here. Your question is not understandable.